# configuration.rb:140:in `const_get': uninitialized constant ActionDispatch::Session::EncryptedCookieStore (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, migration, scaffold

I've been stuck on this error for about 3 days now and I can't figure out how to correct it. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm on a Windows machine by the way and I'm using Ruby v.1.9.3p392 & Rails v. 3.2.13

The command I issued before the error was:

**'rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string'**

This is the error that follows:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/a
pplication/configuration.rb:140:in `const_get': uninitialized constant ActionDis
patch::Session::EncryptedCookieStore (NameError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:140:in `session_store'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/application.rb:273:in `block in default_middleware_stack'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/application.rb:237:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/application.rb:237:in `default_middleware_stack'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `app'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:31:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from C:/ruby/rails_projects/demo_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (r
equired)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/commands.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

This is my configuration.rb file (it doesn't show anything about "Encrypted")

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/string/encoding'
require 'active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting'
require 'active_support/file_update_checker'
require 'rails/engine/configuration'

module Rails
  class Application
    class Configuration < ::Rails::Engine::Configuration
      attr_accessor :allow_concurrency, :asset_host, :asset_path, :assets,
                    :cache_classes, :cache_store, :consider_all_requests_local,
                    :dependency_loading, :exceptions_app, :file_watcher, :filter_parameters,
                    :force_ssl, :helpers_paths, :logger, :log_tags, :preload_frameworks,
                    :railties_order, :relative_url_root, :reload_plugins, :secret_token,
                    :serve_static_assets, :ssl_options, :static_cache_control, :session_options,
                    :time_zone, :reload_classes_only_on_change, :whiny_nils

      attr_writer :log_level
      attr_reader :encoding

      def initialize(*)
        super
        self.encoding = "utf-8"
        @allow_concurrency             = false
        @consider_all_requests_local   = false
        @filter_parameters             = []
        @helpers_paths                 = []
        @dependency_loading            = true
        @serve_static_assets           = true
        @static_cache_control          = nil
        @force_ssl                     = false
        @ssl_options                   = {}
        @session_store                 = :cookie_store
        @session_options               = {}
        @time_zone                     = "UTC"
        @log_level                     = nil
        @middleware                    = app_middleware
        @generators                    = app_generators
        @cache_store                   = [ :file_store, "#{root}/tmp/cache/" ]
        @railties_order                = [:all]
        @relative_url_root             = ENV["RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT"]
        @reload_classes_only_on_change = true
        @file_watcher                  = ActiveSupport::FileUpdateChecker
        @exceptions_app                = nil

        @assets = ActiveSupport::OrderedOptions.new
        @assets.enabled                  = false
        @assets.paths                    = []
        @assets.precompile               = [ Proc.new{ |path| !File.extname(path).in?(['.js', '.css']) },
                                             /(?:\/|\\|\A)application\.(css|js)$/ ]
        @assets.prefix                   = "/assets"
        @assets.version                  = ''
        @assets.debug                    = false
        @assets.compile                  = true
        @assets.digest                   = false
        @assets.manifest                 = nil
        @assets.cache_store              = [ :file_store, "#{root}/tmp/cache/assets/" ]
        @assets.js_compressor            = nil
        @assets.css_compressor           = nil
        @assets.initialize_on_precompile = true
        @assets.logger                   = nil
      end

      def compiled_asset_path
        "/"
      end

      def encoding=(value)
        @encoding = value
        if "ruby".encoding_aware?
          silence_warnings do
            Encoding.default_external = value
            Encoding.default_internal = value
          end
        else
          $KCODE = value
          if $KCODE == "NONE"
            raise "The value you specified for config.encoding is " \
                  "invalid. The possible values are UTF8, SJIS, or EUC"
          end
        end
      end

      def paths
        @paths ||= begin
          paths = super
          paths.add "config/database",    :with => "config/database.yml"
          paths.add "config/environment", :with => "config/environment.rb"
          paths.add "lib/templates"
          paths.add "log",                :with => "log/#{Rails.env}.log"
          paths.add "public"
          paths.add "public/javascripts"
          paths.add "public/stylesheets"
          paths.add "tmp"
          paths
        end
      end

      # Enable threaded mode. Allows concurrent requests to controller actions and
      # multiple database connections. Also disables automatic dependency loading
      # after boot, and disables reloading code on every request, as these are
      # fundamentally incompatible with thread safety.
      def threadsafe!
        self.preload_frameworks = true
        self.cache_classes = true
        self.dependency_loading = false
        self.allow_concurrency = true
        self
      end

      # Loads and returns the contents of the #database_configuration_file. The
      # contents of the file are processed via ERB before being sent through
      # YAML::load.
      def database_configuration
        require 'erb'
        YAML::load(ERB.new(IO.read(paths["config/database"].first)).result)
      end

      def log_level
        @log_level ||= Rails.env.production? ? :info : :debug
      end

      def colorize_logging
        @colorize_logging
      end

      def colorize_logging=(val)
        @colorize_logging = val
        ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber.colorize_logging = val
        self.generators.colorize_logging = val
      end

      def session_store(*args)
        if args.empty?
          case @session_store
          when :disabled
            nil
          when :active_record_store
            ActiveRecord::SessionStore
          when Symbol
            ActionDispatch::Session.const_get(@session_store.to_s.camelize)
          else
            @session_store
          end
        else
          @session_store = args.shift
          @session_options = args.shift || {}
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'



group :development do
    gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.7'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.2'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

group :production do
    gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
#gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
#gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.0.1'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

Ok, so after removing the word 'Encrypted_' from the session_store.rb file. It took away the EncryptedCookieStore (NameError) and the following errors below have now come up, but I'm unsure if they are related:

```
C:\ruby\rails_projects\demo_app>rails generate scaffold User name:string email:s
tring
      invoke  active_record
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/act
ive_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:55:in `method_missing': undefined method `migrati
on_error=' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3
.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:66:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3
.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:65:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3
.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:65:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3
.2.13/lib/active_record/base.rb:720:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/generators/named_base.rb:166:in `pluralize_table_names?'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/generators/named_base.rb:114:in `table_name'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3
.2.13/lib/rails/generators/active_record/model/model_generator.rb:17:in `create_
migration_file'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `block in invoke_all'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `map'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_all'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/group.rb:233:in `dispatch'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:109:in `invoke'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/group.rb:278:in `block in _invoke_for_class_method'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/shell.rb:74:in `with_padding'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/group.rb:267:in `_invoke_for_class_method'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/group.rb:150:in `_invoke_from_option_orm'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `block in invoke_all'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `map'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_all'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/group.rb:233:in `dispatch'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/base.rb:439:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/generators.rb:171:in `invoke'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/commands/generate.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/commands.rb:29:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 6):

Go into `config/initializers/session_store.rb` and change:

```
App::Application.config.session_store :encrypted_cookie_store, key: '_app_session'
```

to:

```
App::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_app_session'
```

Encrpted cookie store was removed recently. Hope it helps.

Comment: I came across this issue upgrading from Rails 4.0.0.beta1 to 4.0.0.rc1 too. Your answer fixed the problem - thanks!

Comment: Thank you - that worked but seemed to bring up a whole bunch of other errors after re-running the command again. I'm unsure if they are related.

Comment: @LilithX can you post the other issues you are getting, just append them to your original question or start a new one.

Comment: Issue happened when upgrading from rails 4.0.0.beta1 to 4.1.0. This solved it. Thanks!